# @helper.repeat in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I don't understand how to describe `@helper`.repeat in play2.2.1.

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.send) {

    @helper.repeat(
        field = form1("input"), min = 3
    ) {fld =>
        @helper.inputText(
            field = fld, '_label ->"input"
        )
    }
}
```

It is the part `fld => @helper.inputText(field = fld)` that I can't understand.
What does it mean?
I know Java, so I assume it is a functional writing, but in above code, where does the variable `fld` come from?
And why the tip of the arrow indicates `@helper.inputText(field = fld)`?
why is `fld` the value of field in `@helper.inputText`?
I have googled, but I couldn't find an enough explanation for a beginner.
I am not sure of Scala's grammar.
Please explain above code for a beginner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original Answer

This seems to be a bit overcomplicated. There is no need to assign values by hand. Usually you would write a repeater like this:

```
@helper.repeat(form1("input"), min = 3) { fld =>
  @helper.inputText(fld, '_label ->"input")
}
```

In functional programming this is a so called [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). You may know other scala built in higher-order functions like `map`, `filter` or `foreach`. `@helper.repeat` is very similar to `foreach`. `form1("input")` refers to a collection of values you want to display. `min = 1` tells the repeater to show at least one field. Finally within `{ fld => ... }` you iterate over all values defined in your collection.

In other words: `{ fld => ... }` is just an anonymous function that takes a single `Field` parameter (`fld`) and displays a text input for that specific field.

### Follow Up

Ok, I'm trying to follow up your questions from the comments. Let's start by the signature of `helper.repeat`. There is no magic involved here, it's just a regular Scala function:

```
helper.repeat(field: Field, min: Int)(fieldRenderer: (fld: Field) => Html): Seq[Html]
```

In Scala, functions can have multiple parameter lists. Here we have two. The first parameter list takes two parameters: `field` and `min`. The second parameter list takes a single function as parameter: `fieldRenderer`. `fieldRenderer` itself takes again a single parameter (`fld`) and returns `Html`.

The important thing is, you are not passing "data" but a function instead.  To clear this up:

The signature `fieldRenderer: (fld: Field) => Html`

is equal to `def fieldRenderer(fld: Field): Html`

This means, you can do anything within this function, as long as it returns Html. That's exactly what happens in the example at the very top. You pass a `Field` and return `Html`. You do that by calling `@helper.inputText`.

Now `repeat` first gets a `List[Field]` from `field` you pass as first parameter. This list corresponds to the String List of your container class. Also `repeat` ensures there is at least one element in that list. This is, because you passed `1` as `min`. Then the function `fieldRenderer` is applied to all elements in our list.

A pseudo code implementation of `repeat` could look like this:

```
def repeat(field: Field, min: Int)(fieldRenderer: (fld: Field) => Html): Seq[Html] {
  val list: List[Field] = field.getFields

  var output: List[Html] = List()
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    val element: Field = list.get(i)
    val html: Html = fieldRenderer(element)
    output += html
  }

  return output
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Finally within { fld => ... } you iterate over all values defined in your collection."  I'm not sure of the meaning.  Do you mean by writing { fld => ... }, I can repeat values defined in my collection?   My collection corresponding with the created form is the very simple container class just having only a String List as its field.   I'm afraid, but is it your mistake?

Comment: And one more thing.     "{ fld => ... } is just an anonymous function that takes a single Field parameter (fld) and displays a text input for that specific field."  So sorry, I can't understand this sentence well ,neither.  I can understand { fld => ... } is just an anonymous class, but does it require two arguments, "fld" and " '_label ->"input""?    And after all, what is the argument "fld"?  Where did it come from?

Comment: Updated the answer, hope that helps :) Let me know if it's still a mystery.

Comment: Thank you very very much.   I can fully understand.  However Let me confirm one more thing.   Don't worry, just confirmation.  In my example, "                    @helper.repeat(form1("input"), min = 3) { fld =>
  @helper.inputText(fld, '_label ->"input")
}", the variable "fld" is considered to be very similar to the variable used in extended for statement in Java which is for example for(String s : names) where names is a collection or array variable.    Is my expectation true?

Comment: The behavior is somewhat similar, but those are completely different things. With enhanced for statements in Java you are basically assigning a value to a helper variable. However in the example above, you are passing a function to `helper.repeat` that takes a parameter `Field`. Maybe this gets more clear by adding a type to `fld`: `@helper.repeat(...) { (fld: Field) => @helper.inputText... }`. (In scala types are often omitted for brevity. Those will be inferred then automatically by the compiler).

Comment: I'm so sorry for persistent asking.   You explained that in the example I showed the first parameter "field" is a collection parameter and the function "fieldRenderer" takes "fld" that refers the collection in the second argument list. So, if the collection has 2 elements, the function is applied two times and refers these two values.   At the same time, Java's extended for statement refers a collection list or array that is taken. And if the number of elements of the collection list is two, repentance is two times.   In that point, I think these treatment are very similar.

Comment: However, you mentioned "With enhanced for statements in Java you are basically assigning a value to a helper variable.".     What situation do you consider?    What does it mean by that?

Comment: That's what I meant by saying "the behavior is similar". In this particular case `helper.repeat` iterates over the collection from `field`. This is part of the implementation of `repeat`. Other functions behave totally different. In the pseudo code implementation I used a plain old for loop. You could use an enhanced for statement as well: `for(Field element : list) { ... fieldRenderer(element) ...}`. With every iteration a value from the collection is assigned to `element`. And then within that loop `fieldRenderer` is called passing that particular element.

Comment: Oh, I understand what situation you indicated on your previous comment, and maybe you want to tell me that these two things "extended for statement and this Scala's system" are different. However, it is not still clear.   What's the explicit difference?   You said these were different in the point that these internal structure or internal processing are different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127385/discussion-between-roman-and-kazuya-tomita).